# How to get clear borders for windows in RDC

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, themes

How to get clear borders for windows in RDC?

I am using Windows 11

I am RDCing to my server but the windows have no borders which make it harder to tell which window is when i open multiple windows.

Here is an example

[image]

is there a way i can force windows borders on RDC?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the Windows Performance Settings.

Under visual settings, choose “Adjust for best appearance.”

Comment: where does this option exist? I am looking at the RDC Display settings and I using the Highest Quality color depth

Comment: @asmgx it’s not an RDP setting. It’s a system performance setting in the control panel on the server.